# How to use a column from a future dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

I just dont seem to be able to understand how to reference a column from a dataframe returned from a future promise in shiny

```
  observeEvent(input$user_btn,{
    Resultsdf$data<-myResultsFunction()
    future({Resultsdf$data})%...>%
    Resultsdf$data$Acolumn<-gsub("blabla","Replace_me",Resultsdf$data$Acolumn) 
    Resultsdf$data$Comments<-"Please state plan here"
})
```

How do I reference `Acolumn` and `Comments` as part of the promise or if I cant do that then how do I place the result of the promise in a new dataframe so I can reference it?

where

```
Resultsdf<-reactiveValues(data = data.frame())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example, the data.frame is stored in a `reactiveVal` once the future is resolved:

```
library(shiny)
library(promises)
library(future)
library(datasets)
plan(multiprocess)

myResultsFunction <- function(){
  Sys.sleep(5)
  return(iris)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("user_btn", "user_btn")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Resultsdf <- reactiveVal()
  
  observeEvent(input$user_btn, {
    future({myResultsFunction()}) %...>% Resultsdf()
  })
  
  observeEvent(Resultsdf(), {
    print(Resultsdf()$Sepal.Length)
    print(Resultsdf()$Species)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Result]

The same pattern is used in this [official article](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/shiny.html#observers-1).

---

**Edit** - Here is how to do the same for reactiveValues:

```
library(shiny)
library(promises)
library(future)
library(datasets)
plan(multiprocess)

myResultsFunction <- function(){
  Sys.sleep(5)
  return(iris)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("user_btn", "user_btn")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Resultsdf <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame()) 
  
  observeEvent(input$user_btn, {
    future({myResultsFunction()}) %...>% (function(result){Resultsdf$data <- result})
  })
  
  observeEvent(Resultsdf$data, {
    print(Resultsdf$data$Sepal.Length)
    print(Resultsdf$data$Species)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

PS: Please consider providing full reproducible examples (not only code snippets).

Comment: Hi @ismirsehgal. I tried your code but I got the error:  Warning: Error in observeEventExpr: could not find function "Resultsdf"
Stack trace (innermost first):
    62: observeEventExpr
     4: <Anonymous>
     3: do.call
     2: print.shiny.appobj
     1: <Promise>
Unhandled promise error: could not find function "Resultsdf"

Comment: `Resultsdf()` isn't used in the future. Are you sure you copied everything correctly? It's working fine on my system.

Comment: Aha.Sorry my mistake. Works fine thanks. What if I wanted to use reactiveValues (ie to store a dataframe). Would there be any difference?

Comment: The assignment is a little more inconvenient - please see my edit.